# Jquery .split(",") then show every :nth-child(2)

Tags: jquery, split

How could one find every 3rd item in an array after .split()?

newItems = "1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0"

shows just the first 0:

```
var test = ("" + newItems).split(",")[2];
```

I am trying to do something like this and show 0,0,0,0:

```
var test = ("" + newItems).split(",")[:nth-child(2)];
```

Comment: `var test = ("" + newItems).split(",")[2];` .... use index `2`

Comment: I am trying to show every 3rd in the entire string v.s. just the first one

Comment: First 3 items or 3rd item?.

Comment: I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when I try var test = ("" + newItems).split(",")[:nth-child(3n) ]; (also should actually be 2n I believe because 0 counts in array)

Comment: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dnLksx9g/) just like the code that you are using.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/dnLksx9g/1/ - trying to get all 0's to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var newItems = "1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0",
    everyThirdItem = newItems.split(",")
                       .filter(function(_, idx) { return ((idx + 1) % 3) === 0 });

console.log(everyThirdItem)
```

Comment: Hey andreas, to keep the example simple I used just 0's but they will not always be 0's I cut out === 0 but it seems to not do every 3rd

Comment: `=== 0` has nothing to do with the one you showing it the index of you want to get if the index is divisible by 3 meaning every 3rd

Comment: @Jeff If you remove the condition "_remove every third item_" then it cannot work... ;). `.filter()` expects a function which returns `true` (= keep the item) or `false` (= ignore this item). The `return` part does exactly this. If the value (index + 1) of the current item is divisible by 3 (`idx + 1` can be divided by `3` without remainder ([Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))) it returns `true` otherwise `false`.

Comment: Thanks Andres! I just realized it wasnt fetching zeros because the array I am working with starts with an outliar value then it should be every other 3 ex [Name,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0];

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you mean:

```
var test = [];
for(var i=2; i<("" + newItems).split(",").length; i+= 3) {
    test.push(("" + newItems).split(",")[i]);
}
```

I hope this helps!